# jquery.jeditable is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery

i am using jquery.jeditable and every time i submit i get This error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.coacharabia.com/save.php. Origin http://coacharabia.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Note that the file and the save.php are on the same server in the same folder . the code am using is :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.coacharabia.com/save.php', {
         cancel    : 'Cancel',
         submit    : 'Save',
         indicator : '<img src="jeditable/img/indicator.gif">',
         tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
     });

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try replacing:

```
$('.edit').editable('http://www.coacharabia.com/save.php', {
```

By:

```
$('.edit').editable('http://coacharabia.com/save.php', {
```

Or just:

```
$('.edit').editable('save.php', {
```